# how to deploy fastapi app on shared hosting using wsgi server?

Tags: python, cpanel, fastapi, passenger, asgi

in a recent article,
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-deploy-fastapi-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I read that fastapi "can work with WSGI if needed". I was wondering how?

I did a whole project with fastapi and  tried to deploy it on cpanel shared hosting(my option for the moment) ,

in the wsgi.py file I used a2sg library

```
from main import app
from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware
application = ASGIMiddleware(app)
```

but I get 503 temporary busy, try again when I browse to the page

so, how can I deploy my app , I deployed django with ease but fasapi is an issue as it mainly uses ASGI.
is it also possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are few checks you need to do apart from adding the A2WSGI Middleware.

1. Adding empty py files named as `__init__.py` in each directory including root of application
2. Create new `passenger.py` file with same code you have given in `wsgi.py`
3. Use the above `passenger.py` file while setting up the python application, also keep `wsgi.py` as you have prepared already in same directory.
   (Cpanel->Setup Python App)
4. Run `Uvicorn` server with unused port like `60323` etc.
5. Restart the app from the Python Application Options

Answer (score 0):

I have created this simple repository on github to show how to run under Apachepython a basic webapp based on ASGI (with fastapi) using a WSGI server: [danielemaddaluno/pyjel](https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/pyjel)

This is the project:

```
.
├── app
│   └── app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.sh
└── wsgi.py
```

The `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os, sys

virtenv = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/venv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    if sys.version.split(' ')[0].split('.')[0] == '3':
        exec(compile(open(virtualenv, "rb").read(), virtualenv, 'exec'), dict(__file__=virtualenv))
    else:
        execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~'))
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~') + '/ROOT/')

from app import app
from a2wsgi import ASGIMiddleware
application = ASGIMiddleware(app.app)
```

The `app.py` file:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

The `requirements.txt` file:

```
a2wsgi
uvicorn
fastapi
```

The `setup.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
deactivate
```